# Irrational integration

Tags: integration

I'm having problems solving this type of irrational integral: 
$$\int_{}^{}\frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{(2x-3)\sqrt[5]{2x-3} + \sqrt[5]{2x-3}}dx$$

I've tried using the following substitution: $2x-3 = t^5$ but hopeless.
If anyone sees how the integral should be solved please reply to my question.

P.S. This is the result that I should get:
$$\frac{5}{2}\left[\ln(\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+1) -  \arctan\sqrt[5]{2x-3}\right] +c$$

Comment: That substitution should transform the integral into one with a rational integrand. Perhaps you can include the first few steps of your attempt, so that would-be respondents can give better-targeted advice?

Comment: After derivating the substition and including it in the integral I've end with the followingequitation:
$\frac{5}{2}\int_{}^{}\frac{2t^4}{t^5-1}dx - \frac{5}{2}\int_{}^{}\frac{t^3}{t^5-1}dx$

Now the 1st integral is solved easily and I get this result for the 1st one:
$ln|t^5-1|$

Comment: haha, same excersise sheet guys???

Comment: Unfortunately I got stuck with the same integral $\int_{}^{}\frac{t^3}{t^5-1}$
How should I divide the fraction after I decompose the lower fraction?

Comment: This is at least the third time this very same question's been asked in the last 24 hours. Either the same user is signing up with different nicks or else a huge group of students somewhere (apparently East Europe) got the same exercise. And they all (or he) are stuck at the very same point.

Comment: You'll have to try a partial fraction decomposition.  You might consider checking out the answers that the other versions of this question got...

Comment: Note that [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%285%2F2%28ln%28%282x-3%29^%281%2F5%29%2B1%29-arctan%28%282x-3%29^%281%2F5%29%29%29%29) does not agree with the proposed result, at least not in an obvious way.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that should be the answer? I used a calculator to evaluate the derivative of the result that we should get.
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{5}{2}ln\left((2x-3)^{1/5}-1\right)-arctan(2x-3)^{1/5}\right)$$
$$=\dfrac{5 (2 x-3)^{2/5}-2 (2 x-3)^{1/5}+7}{5 (2 x-3)^{4/5} \left((2 x-3)^{1/5}-1\right) \left((2 x-3)^{2/5}+1\right)}
$$
I used the same calculator to evaluate the integral and it does not look as simple as the desired solution.

Comment: You have a typo, I think, which might be why: your $-1$ in the first line should be a $+1$.